# How would I delay a slow React child from re-rendering so the parent can repaint the dom immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Suppose you had a React App component with a child component that was slow to mount (in my case a 3rd party document editor). The App has to re-render whenever the document changes, and the two child components (the header (which simply displays title, id), the document editor (slow to initially render when initializing a document)) should be able to re-render and repaint the dom as soon as they finish updating. However, the document editor, because it is a slow to initialize, prevents the header from repainting until it is complete. Below is an illustration, where the `FastChild` will not be repainted until the `SlowChild` returns.

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FastChild count={count} />
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}>increment</button>
      <SlowChild count={count}/>
    </div>
  );
}

function FastChild({ count }) {
  return (
    <h1>{count}</h1>
  )
}

function SlowChild({ count }) {

  return veryLongList.map(()=> (
    <div>
      {`count ${count}`}
    </div>
  ))
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot make changes the document editor (which would be the SlowChild component in this example).

Comment: What is "slow" about the "slow child" component? React is optimized to run quite well out-of-the-box, and it's my experience if there are significant performance issues it's more likely to be from something we've done ourselves than anything React. What is `SlowChild` doing that makes it slow?

Comment: You may find the concurrent rendering of React 18 informative, just an FYI: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html

Comment: Hi Drew Reese, the `SlowChild` is a third party (computationally heavy) rich text editor, that takes id and content as props. I also built my own custom header to display some information about the document to be rendered in the text editor. So both my header and the editor rely on the same prop reference, and therefore re-render together when i switch documents, but my header stalls until the text editor finishing rendering (i'm not sure why it's so slow to initialize on document change)

Comment: concurrent rendering seems exactly what i need, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the component only need to initialize once, when it mounts? Or are you saying it really is just slow to rerender? Also regarding the concurrent rendering, welcome. 

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to keep a copy of the prop in state, and use `shouldComponentUpdate` to delay the slow component from rendering using `setImmediate`

```
class DelayedSlowChild extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      localCount: props.count,
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    if (nextProps.count !== this.props.count) {
      setImmediate(() => this.setState({ localCount: nextProps.count }))
      return false;
    } else if (this.state.localCount !== nextState.localCount) {
      return true;
    }
    return false
  }

  render() {
    veryLongList.map(i => (
        <div>
          {`${i} ${this.props.count}`}
        </div>
    ))
  }
}
```